# How can I hide a label after few seconds using google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a simple application where the user press a button and a welcome message is shown. I need this message(label) to be hidden after few seconds, say 5 secs.
I couldn't find a function like setTimeout() in google apps script.

Can someone give an idea how I could implement this?

(as you can see, not an experienced programmer).

Thanks!!

Comment: Ses this post for a better solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21483652/automatically-close-a-google-apps-script-uiapp-after-five-seconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution. The logic is to have two the button click handlers. the 1st one makes the label visible and the 2nd one sleeps 5 seconds and after hides the label.

```
function doGet(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  var btn = app.createButton().setText('Test');
  var lblVisible = app.createLabel('Visible Test').setVisible(false).setId('lblVisible');
  panel.add(btn);
  panel.add(lblVisible);
  var handler = app.createServerHandler('onBtnClick');
  var handlerWait = app.createServerHandler('onWaitEvent');
  handler.addCallbackElement(panel);
  handlerWait.addCallbackElement(panel);
  btn.addClickHandler(handler);
  btn.addClickHandler(handlerWait);
  app.add(panel);
  return app;
}

function onWaitEvent(e) {
  Utilities.sleep(5 * 1000);
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var lblVisible = app.getElementById('lblVisible');
  lblVisible.setVisible(false);
  return app;
}

function onBtnClick(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var lblVisible = app.getElementById('lblVisible');
  lblVisible.setVisible(true);
  return app;
}
```

Comment: @Megabyte1024 why do you app.close() in both handler functions ? this doesn't make sense... you shouldn't close the app when you setVisible the label (function(onCloseClick()) the code you provided simply cannot work, it never shows the test label ;-)

Comment: @Serge insas: Corrected the code. The code almost completely is taken from my previous code which I used to play around [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314772/google-script-how-to-close-an-ui-from-the-serverhandler-while-another-functio)

Comment: @Serge insas: BTW. The code works even in initial edition. The close lines are ignored. The label "Visible Test" appears after the button is clicked and disappears in 5 secs.

Comment: ? not with chrome here... I tested before to be sure, anyway the code was not 'logical' if relying on 'ignoring some instruction'. no offense from me, sorry if I was looking harsh

Comment: @Serge insas: Not a problem. I use both Chrome (20.0.1132.47 m) and Firefox (13.0.1), checked the initial release before posting it - everything worked and works.

Comment: I understand what happened !! To test your script I modified it to use it on a spreadsheet  (using   var d=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();d.show(app)) ... that's why it didn't work here .

Comment: The answer is helpful for the topic starter. The code is fixed. The cause of not worked code is found. Everyone is happy.

Answer (score 1):

Progress indicator solution etc, this works. It lets you chain events, I have used it several times.

Updating a widget value on the go. productforums.google.com/d/topic/apps-script/lABoP-cJcGQ/…